# How do I release an UIImageView allocated like this?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimageview, release

I've allocated a UIImageView inside the setBackground method of my tableview cell like this:

```
 [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:rowBackground]];
```

When i run Analyse in XCode 4 it highlights this line as a possible memory leak. How do i release this UIImageView as Ive not got a pointer to reference from a release call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either allocate it differently (i.e. store it in an ivar and release that), or call `autorelease` on it, like this:

```
[cell setBackgroundView:[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:rowBackground] autorelease]];
```

Comment: I just worked it out. I tried autoreleasing like this but for some reason Code Sense didnt like it. Did this instead which works.

Comment: cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:rowBackground] autorelease];

Answer (score 1):

Send it an [autorelease](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW5) message:

```
[cell setBackgroundView:[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:rowBackground] autorelease]];
```

With an autorelease message  you declare that you don't want to own the object beyond the scope in which you sent the message.